# mysql connector throwing "Wrongargumentexception Malformed database URL"

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

> I am using the below mysql url to connect the database.

jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://msdb-mysqlserver-npd1:3340/devuser?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false

When i am initiating the connection it is throwing the below error.

> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentExceptions : Malformed Database URL , failed to parse the main url sections

i am using mysql-connector-java-8.0.11 version

Comment: are you connecting to mysql? or sql server? they are different products and probably the confusion in your connector URL.

Comment: What is the database server URL? Is it localhost?

Comment: @danblack -- I am trying to connect mysql only

Comment: @Klaus : it is not a localhost and the server is a remote mysql server

Comment: @ScaryWombat   three different nodes for the same database  to switch if anyone of them is not working  , to handle that load balance is mentioned there in the url

Comment: seems consistent with [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-managing-load-balanced-connections.html), if you replace the hostname with IP do you get the same error?

Comment: Is it valid to have `loadBalance` with only one host - missing `,`